# How to solve this boundary-value problem in electrostatics?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electricity, potential, differential-equations

I was reading *The Feynman Lectures on Physics, Vol. 2* and came across the following on page 7-1.

> There are a few problems for which Eq. (7.1) can be solved directly. For example, the problem of a charged conductor having the shape of an ellipsoid of revolution can be solved exactly in terms of known special functions.

Eq. (7.1) : $\quad\Delta \varphi= 0\qquad$ ($\varphi$ is used for electric potential).

I've just started learning differential and integral calculus of vectors and I want to go through the solution to the ellipsoid problem that is mentioned just to better understand how one would go about solving differential equations in electrostatic situations such as this one.

So, could one of you please post a step-by-step solution to the mentioned problem?

Comment: I've added the homework-and-exercises tag. In the future, please use this tag for this type of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrriting out a solution step by step wold be too long for this site, but the necessary special functions and links to  where the problem is discussed can be found in: "[Lamé function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lam%C3%A9_function)". In particular see
"[Prolate spheroidal wave function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolate_spheroidal_wave_function)" and "[Oblate spheroidal wave function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oblate_spheroidal_wave_function)".

I do suggest however that you start with simpler problems such as the solution to electrostatics problems with spherical symmetry.

Comment: Yeah, starting on PDEs with an ellipsoidal boundary value problem would be like learning to drive on a car with manual transmission with a stiff clutch.  You *could* do it, but it's a lot easier to start with a simpler case.

Comment: Thankyou very much! And I will start out with simpler cases first. Thanks for the advice and the links.